# Unexpected token

Tags: html, output, unexpected-token

My friends and I are trying to make a website from scratch and we have barely ever touched html. We have got a private domain, but we just started and don't seem to know how to define this unexpected token found on line 29. Any help would be well appreciated. This is the only thing limiting us to run our code (I think).

`<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>`

[image of line 29 (where token is said to be unexpected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POtAJ.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7VIg.png)

[line 28-44](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwSpi.png)

````
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="936710688088-5fupofi0g9i8nb2ua7tftc9gkt4ndhue.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }
    <a href="#" onClick="signOut();">Sign out</a>                                                  

  function signOut() 
  {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () 
    {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }

    </script>
    
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: Please notice that you are closing the script twice with </script>. Also try onClick, with the capital C. I also notice a curly bracket ( { ) above your <a href="". It's not a valid token in HTML. close your php/js first with ?>

Comment: The error is at the upper line. As i can see there is an ending curly brace there. Did you use a java script code there without a ending </script> tag? Please check it first. And if not please add complete set of code here.